# rxjava run multiple observable sequence with condition

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

i have 4 observable, and i want call it sequence

```
Observable1 //return boolean
-> Observable2 // if(Observable1 result == true) { call Observable3 } else { call observable4 }
-> Observable3 // call Observable4
-> Observable4
-> subscribe();
```

i tried it, but when Observable1 result is false onCompleted called

```
Observable
    .fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return false;
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<Boolean, Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(Boolean aBoolean) {
            if(aBoolean) {
                return Observable.just("to Observable2");
            }
            return null; // to Observable 3
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(String s) {
            return Observable.just(1);  //to Observable3
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Boolean> call(Integer integer) {
            return Observable.just(true); //success
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.e("TAG", "onCompleted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onError", e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Boolean bool) {
            Log.e("TAG", "onNext");
        }
    });
```

how can achieve to this ?
thanks

Comment: I think you mean you have 4 task(function) rather than 4 observable. You have a task flow task1 -> task2 -> (task3 -> ) task4, task3 only be executed when task1 returns true. Is my understand right?

Comment: And recommend post your actual use case.

Comment: @DeanXu i posted my solution, see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem with define observables as functions

```
public void run() {
    Observable
            .fromCallable(() -> false)
            .flatMap(bool -> {
                if(bool) {
                    return getObservable2();
                }
                return getObservable3();
            })
            .subscribe(bool -> {
                Log.e("TAG", "onNext");
            }, e -> {
                Log.e("TAG", "onError", e);
            }, () -> {
                Log.e("TAG", "onCompleted");
            });
}

private Observable<Boolean> getObservable2() {
    return Observable
            .just("test")
            .flatMap(s -> getObservable4());
}

private Observable<Boolean> getObservable3() {
    return Observable
            .just(1)
            .flatMap(s -> getObservable4());
}

private Observable<Boolean> getObservable4() {
    return Observable.just(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. Only proposed this based on the first pseudocode you are offering.

```
Observable.just(boolean)
  .flatmap( boolean -> if (boolean) return Observable3 
                       else return Observable.just(boolean))
  .flatmap(boolean -> Observable4)
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: Maybe possible to either return `Observable3` or `Observable4` from the first `flatMap`, and then there is no need for the second?

Comment: According to his pseudocode, he wants to execute Observable4 in any case. I can't know if that was not his intention

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.just(boolean)
  .flatmap( boolean -> if (boolean) 
                          return Observable3.flatmap(observable4) 
                       else return Observable4))
  .subscribe()
```

if the result of first observable is true than obervablr3 is called whose result is then flat mapped into the observable4 second case is if the result of first observable is false then it will call observable4 directly and the result is  subscribes in first observable only

Comment: Add an explanation describing why that should work and what the OP did wrong.

Answer (score -3):

This is how I would attempt to solve your problem but it doesn't use flatmap.

```
Observable2.subscribe( aBoolean -> if(aBoolean){
        Observable3.subscribe();
    } else {
        Observable2.subscribe( result -> Observable3.subscribe());
}
```

You should never return null from an Observable

Comment: I don't that's true - it's perfectly reasonable to return `null` if the downstream doesn't care about the actual emission. What I would avoid doing is subscribing inside an Observer, as the code in this answer does: that creates a complex nested chain - basically one of the problems (Callback Hell) that RX actually solves. Also, you can no longer build on top of that chain, as it terminates inside the Observer.

Comment: Well, in RxJava2 it's actually illegal to return null. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4475

Comment: Didn't know they disallowed in in 2.x. I guess it's a good idea to use `Completable` where possible.